# Display database value in textarea

Tags: php, html

I am trying to display the value of a textarea in a form that will enable someone to edit its value. The textarea displays nothing but I checked the database and there is a 2 sentence value. Here is the code I am using:

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="55" name="P1Bio" value="<?=$record['P1Bio']?>">
</textarea>
```

P1Bio is the field. On the same form, I am also getting values from textboxes and it is working fine. Here is the code that I am using for text boxes:

```
<input type="text" size="90" name="P1Email" value="
<?=$record['P1Email']?>">
```

Can someone please tell me why the textarea is not showing anything? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `value` attribute with [textareas](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/textarea.html).

You need to put the content in between the open and closing tags like this:

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="55" name="P1Bio"><?=$record['P1Bio']?></textarea>
```

Comment: Dammit, I'm as late as always. :)

Comment: You should not put an enter in  between textarea opening and closing tags. This creates actual linebreaks within the content, thus altering whatever content is placed in between.

Comment: Worked great!  Thanks for your help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Your php needs to be inside the text area

```
 <textarea><?= $record['P1Bio'] ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="55" name="P1Bio><?=$record['P1Bio']?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike texts (like `<input type="text">`), content in `textarea`s are inside the tags:

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="55" name="P1Bio" value=""><?=$record['P1Bio']?></textarea>
```

Some information regarding this: [HTML  Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp)